# regular expressions in Python month and year search

Tags: python

Here is my problem. I have a complex text file with 32 articles. Since each article starts with 1 out of 32 DOCUMENTS, 2 out of 32 DOCUMENTS etc, using the following code I split the text into the different articles using:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):        
           sections.append("".join(current))
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))
```

I am now trying to extract the date of each article. I have noticed that the date is either in the 4th or the 5th line of the beginning of each article. Therefore I manage to create a function with this relevant lines by:

```
def main():
    for i in range(len(sections)): 
        date_row4 = (sections[i].split("\n")[4].split(" "))     
        date_row5 = (sections[i].split("\n")[5].split(" "))

        print(date_row4)
        print(date_row5)
```

Which gets me the following list:
[image: list retrieved by running the above code]

What I am trying to find now, is the month and the year only by using the following:

```
months = 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'

month = re.findall(r' \w+ months',date_row4 or date_row5)
year = re.findall(r' \d^20', date_row4 or date_row5 )
```

Nevertheless, is not working. I just started to learn Python so there are so many things that I can imagine are going wrong. Any help would be much appreciate it.

Kind regards,

Andres

Comment: Could you post samples of your file?

Comment: Is there some reason your question doesn't start with the part of "Which gets me the following list"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd use regular expressions for this. The `time` module has tools to parse dates.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime('December 29, 2005 Thursday', "%B %d, %Y %A").tm_year
2005
```

If you have some lines missing the day of the week you could use a `try`/`except` block with the more common case first

Comment: Wouldn't work because of non-zeropadded dates, like 'April 5' ;-(

Comment: my bad, you're right. That's way better than regexp then :-)
I'd also suggest `datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, your question really starts at "which gets me the following list". (If so, why the part up to that, if I might ask).

While it's of course possible to use `re` to very precisely match your exact pattern, I've often found that using a fraction of its power, is far easier. The following `exp` using the very simple regular expression:

```
exp = re.compile(r'(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)')
```

can be used to specify the general form you want, and can be used as in:

```
m = exp.search('December 29, 2005')
if m:
     m.groups() # This contains the match
```

If you want, you can further check that the matched month is in your `months` variable (which I'd change into a `set` if you choose to do this).

Comment: Since the OP has the list `months`, you could make the initial `(\w+)` more specific by inserting `'|'.join(months)`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire First, if you're the guy who wrote pyparsing - kudos. I completely agree. However, my point was exactly that you sometimes can benefit from re without knowing how to do exactly everything.

Comment: I am, thanks! - I'm actually just now writing up a Meetup tutorial using date parsing as an introductory example. Since the OP has already culled the input file to just those lines containing just date strings, your RE will likely do the trick. I *would* probably make it a little more tolerant of whitespace variations (no space, multiple spaces, etc.) - it's amazing how much junk creeps into "well-formatted" text files. In fact, we already see the OP dealing with some of this, as "the date is either in the 4th or the 5th line of the beginning of each article".

Comment: Good for you, @PaulMcGuire!

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to sort out the regular expressions, the easier one to fix is the year. A regular expression must be in the order the characters will appear:

so assuming all your years are after 2000 then your expression would be 
'20\d\d'

now for the months
unfortunately what you are doing won't work, you cannot just use a list in a regular expression but it is simple to fix:

```
 months = ['January', 'February' ] # etc
 pattern = '|'.join(months) # this makes a string which would look like: January|February
 month = re.search(months, date_row4 or date_row5).group() # this will return a string instead of a list
```

Though there are much better approaches using the datetime module

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
for section in sections: 
    date_row4 = section.split("\n")[4].split(" ")     
    date_row5 = section.split("\n")[5].split(" ")

    match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+\d{1,2},\s+(\d{4})', date_row4)
    if not match:
        match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+\d{1,2},\s+(\d{4})', date_row5)

    if match:
        month = match.group(1)
        year = match.group(2)
```

Upd: Although using date formats is much better.

Comment: The code looks really good, thanks! Nevertheless, I get the following error:  "expected string or bytes-like objects" and is pointing at the line where "match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+\d{1,2},\s+(\d{4})', date_row4))" . Any ideas why?

Comment: @AndresAzqueta `date_row4))"` is there a second closing bracket? It's not needed.

If that's not the case, could you `print date_row4` before that?

Comment: there is not a second parenthesis. And is not allowing me to print(date_row4) and neither print(date_row5)... I obtain the following error: Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in identation

Comment: There's probably a mixup with copy-pasted code, try turning on tab/spaces view in your editor and check once again, it should be consistently one or the other.